# What is the probability that the three friends end up in three different tutorials?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A mathematics course has an enrolment of 60 students. The lecturer will randomly assign $20$ students to each of three tutorials $A$, $B$ and $C$. $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are friends with each other. What is the probability that the three friends end up in three different tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say X gets assigned first, then Y, then Z.

Then Y is assigned to a different tutorial from X with probability $\small{\displaystyle{\frac{40}{59}}}$ ($40$ qualifying seats out of $59$ available).

And Z is assigned to a different tutorial from X,Y with probability $\small{\displaystyle{\frac{20}{58}}}$ ($20$ qualifying seats out of $58$ available).

Hence the probability that X,Y,Z are assigned to three different tutorials is just

$$\frac{40}{59} \cdot \frac{20}{58} = \frac{400}{1711} \approx .234$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the first is put into one tutorial.  There are $59$ possible places to put the next friend, $40$ of which are in the *other* 2 classes.

Now given that this has happened, there are $58$ places the third friend could be assigned, of which $20$ are in the class not containing either friend.

$\frac{40}{59}\times\frac{20}{58}=\frac{400}{1711}$

Comment: You meant $\frac{20}{\color{red}{58}}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, thanks