# What is the probability that at least one of the friends ends up in tutorial $A$, or at least one of the friends ends up in tutorial $B$, (or both)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A mathematics course has an enrolment of $60$ students. The lecturer will randomly assign $20$ students to each of three tutorials $A$, $B$ and $C$. $X,Y$ and $Z$ are friends with each other.

1. What is the probability that the three friends end up in the same tutorial?
2. What is the probability that at least one of the friends ends up in tutorial $A$, or at least one of the friends ends up in tutorial $B$, (or both)?

Let $$m= \frac{\dbinom{57}{17}}{\dbinom{60}{20}}$$ I got $3m$ for the first one and $1-m$ for the second one. Is this correct?

Comment: As you know, your first question has been answered [in your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257865/what-is-the-probability-that-the-three-friends-end-up-in-three-different-tutoria).  For the second question, please show what you have attempted.

Comment: Let m=(57 choose 17)/(60 choose 20). I got 3m for the first one and 1-m for the second one. Is this correct?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: OK. Thanks for editing. But is my answer correct?

Comment: Both your answers are correct.